# Lattice: Levelplot, funny lines?

Tags: r, plot, lattice, levelplot

I am using the R package lattice to make a level plot. I am getting funny horizontal white lines across my panels:
[image]
I do not understand why I am getting these. My H0a values are spaced very closely. There are no missing values either. For example in the bottom right panel I have at H0b=1.0

```
        y        H0b  H0a   
 [1,] 1.021897   1    0.05 
 [2,] 1.043798   1    0.10 
 [3,] 1.065699   1    0.15 
 [4,] 1.087600   1    0.20 
 [5,] 1.109500   1    0.25 
 [6,] 1.131400   1    0.30 
 [7,] 1.153299   1    0.35 
 [8,] 1.175198   1    0.40 
 [9,] 1.197095   1    0.45 
[10,] 1.218991   1    0.50 
[11,] 1.240886   1    0.55 
[12,] 1.262778   1    0.60 
[13,] 1.284667   1    0.65 
[14,] 1.306551   1    0.70 
[15,] 1.328428   1    0.75 
[16,] 1.350292   1    0.80 
[17,] 1.372130   1    0.85 
[18,] 1.393909   1    0.90 
[19,] 1.415481   1    0.95 
[20,] 1.433730   1    1.00
```

Even when I set H0a at fine gradations, this problem does not go away

was hoping to get some help?

Comment: This might be a floating point numerical accuracy issue. Try adding a small fuzz value like 0.0000001 to all the Z values. And do post the code being used and `str(.)` on the dataset.

Comment: thanks for the tip on str(.). the fuzz value trick did not change anything...

Comment: What are R and lattice version you are using (newest?)? Is this happening when you save plot to png? pdf? on-screen? What happens when you add argument `useRaster=TRUE`?

Comment: ............ And do post the code being used and str(.) on the dataset.

Comment: Sorry. don't understand how to post with str(.). I searched for instructions, could you pls point me to it. I will then post it

Comment: Here's the guide to posting data etc. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example Make sure to post the actual code, please.